# How to decrease Traffic Information's z index in Google Map V2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am displaying a route using Polylines in Google Map V2. I am also displaying TrafficInformation of Google Map.

So When I enable traffic information, it is coming above the poly lines.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gxVn.png

As you can see in image that green part is hiding my blue route (polyline). I read other S.O. posts saying changing in z-index will solve the problem. I tried it but nothing is happening. Traffic Information is on the top all the time.

So How can I decrease the z-index of traffic information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't decrease the traffic information, just enable or disable.
My suggestion are:
try to exponentially increase Z index of your route (more than 1000), if even with millions it does not help, make the route larger (increase the width) so you can see your route as background and traffic in overlay.
unfortunately there is no better way :(

Comment: True, I set z-index to 10000, but it didnt help me out. :(

Comment: So you can only make your ruote bigger or disable traffic. Or even ask for a new feature to Google :)

Comment: I think some body already [did it](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6468)

Comment: So apparently they will fix it